# webbacked selenium not supporting captureNetworkTraffic method

Tags: selenium, webdriver

i am using webdriverbackedSelenium  for my tests , i see that it isn't supporting capture network traffic method. can anyone tell me when webdriverbackedselenium is extending default selenium why isn't it supporting  captureNetworkTraffic method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium WebDriver and Selenium RC use fundamentally different mechanisms to automate the browser. RC installed itself as a proxy in some modes of operation, which allowed it to capture all communications between browser and web server. WebDriver's philosophy is designed to more closely emulate the user's experience, including not blindly installing a proxy without the user's knowledge, so WebDriver is not able to capture that traffic by default.

Selenium RC is deprecated, and has been for over two years. It is receiving no attention from the development team, and is unlikely to be improved in the future. However, since many people have significant investments in code using the RC API, the project provides a bridge class, WebDriverBackedSelenium. It is designed to allow you to migrate your RC code to WebDriver over time. It is not intended as a permanent solution. It does not, will not, cannot, and should not implement every single method of the Selenium RC API. It implements enough to allow your code to compile and mostly run, giving you the opportunity to change your code over to the WebDriver API.

If you absolutely require capturing network traffic to the browser using WebDriver, the API allows you to specify a proxy to use with the browser being automated. There are a number of proxies out there which allow you to capture, examine, and even modify the traffic to the browser. Some examples that people have used to good effect are BrowserMob proxy and Fiddler.